# Make PyQt4 Application a Drop Target for Files

Tags: python, cocoa, pyqt4, dock, py2app

Our python application is compiled to a standalone MacOsX application (.app) using py2app, and put to the Dock. Using the [latest py2app from bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/py2app), it is already able to receive files dropped onto it, by having **argv_emulation** set to True in our setup.py. (this setting makes dropped files appear in the sys.argv list when the app is ran).

However, once the application is running, new files dropped onto it won't start another instance of the application. Rather, they will trigger a drag&drop message to be sent to the running application. Ideally we'd like to be able to either make the Dock spawn another application instance, or make our PyQt4 application intercept the Drag&Drop message sent to it. Any hints are greatly appreciated.